# How to add external libraries to ROS cpp file?

Tags: ros-melodic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Could someone explain the proper way how to link external libraries to ros cpp node in the cmake. For example I want to use libserial in my node to control the driver. Fro that I have installed the lib by using this commands:

sudo apt install libserial-dev

And now I have to link that lib in the cmake

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341788/how-to-add-external-libraries-to-ros-cpp-file?/) by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2020-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-01-15**:
Maybe it's outdated but you could try this https://answers.ros.org/question/127866/how-to-utilize-libserial-with-ros-ubuntu-1204-hydro/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to answer my own question, to clarify which way I found and what is the proper as I consider.

Basically, you have to add folder with header files and the library itself. You can do it with find_package, or manually.

The header files you have to include in "include_libraries" like I did:

include_directories(
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${Qt5WebSockets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
/usr/include
)

And the library itself, you can add with "target_link_libraries", like this:

add_executable(driver src/driver_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(driver ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libserial.so)

---

Originally posted by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) with karma: 166 on 2020-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0